# "Тайны и загадки": можно ли так сказать?

Tags: синонимы

У нас вышла книга "Тайны и загадки Крыма". А разве "тайны" и "загадки" — не синонимы? По-моему, в названии звучит явная тавтология.
Хотелось бы узнать мнение экспертов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, вполне нормальное название, хотя и слегка банальное. Разницу в значениях можно при желании найти.

Как мне видится, тайны - это нечто, скрытое от всех, сама атмосфера непознанного, загадочного. Загадки же - это то, что не известно широкому кругу людей, но может стать известным для тех, кто интересуется.

Answer (score 0):

Разница в значениях есть, но не здесь. В данном случае, полагаю, имеет место синонимия - и вытекающий из неё плеоназм. Впрочем, само по себе это не есть что-то криминальное, не всякий плеоназм - зло. Так что критиковать действительно стоит скорее с позиций борьбы с банальностями. Но это уже другой разговор.